# How to set default active slide in Swiper JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I have HTML

```
<div class="swiper-container instance-0" data-id="nav-slider">
  <ul class="swiper-wrapper nav-content__list">
    <li class=" swiper-slide nav-content__item">
      <a class=" link link--ms" href="/news-stories/stories">
        <span class="link__text">
         Stories
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class=" swiper-slide nav-content__item">
      <a class=" link link--ms" href="/news-stories/multimedia">
        <span class="link__text">
          Multimedia
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class=" swiper-slide nav-content__item">
      <a class=" link link--ms" href="/news-stories/press-releases">
        <span class="link__text">
          Press releases
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My js:

```
const $navSlider = $('[data-id="nav-slider"]');
      const $swiperInstances = [];
      const $currentPath = window.location.pathname;
      $navSlider.each(function (index, sliderElement) {
        const $this = $(this);
        $this.addClass(`instance-${index}`);
        $swiperInstances[index] = new Swiper(sliderElement, {
          slidesPerView: 'auto',
          watchOverflow: true,
          initialSlide: '2',
        });
      });
```

But initialSlide don't work for me.
$swiperInstances[index].slideTo(2) don't work too

I need set the default item in the swiperslider

Comment: Try setting data-id="nav-slider" to ul element

Comment: if I enter a custom class name, it will work, but the first element remains the default

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `.slideTo()` in `afterInit()` event.
[documentation](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#event-afterInit)